# Insert into timescaledb filling up ram - wrong chunk_time_interval?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have a postgres table which I would like to migrate to a timescaledb hypertable. I am using the `faster method` from this tutorial https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/migrate-data/same-db/#convert-the-new-table-to-a-hypertable to do so.

The command I am using is: `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;` where new_table is a hypertable

**Is the problem that I have set chunk_time_interval incorrectly?** I used 1h which really should be fine. The total dataset is about 650GB in the original postgres table and spans about 5 months. So that means the average chunk is about 200MB in size which is well below the recommended 25% * 32GB RAM. I actually purposefully chose a number I thought much to low because of additional data I will load to other hypertables in future.

- If this is not the problem then what is?
- Is there a way to limit postgres or timescaledb to not go over a set amount of ram to protect other processes?

Comment: Does the new table have any foreign key constraints, or non-system triggers?

Comment: Yes, there is 1 foreign key constraint

Comment: If thats whats causing it, I could delete it and re-add it afterwards but I will at some point also be adding new data to the table and it shouldn't run out of ram then.

Comment: But the new data will be done in smaller sets than a full refactoring you are doing now, won't they?

Comment: Yes thats right but do you think that this is the thing that's causing this problem?

Comment: It is the only obvious culprit.  I would rule it out before racking my brains for other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem before when using a space partition together with the time partition. Check that the number of chunks you have is not too high and make sure to always include a time range in your query. Whats the output of
`select * from  timescaledb_information.hypertables;`

Does it show a high number of chunks in your hypertable?